# Seconds in taskbar gone after update KB5027231

Tags: windows-update, windows-11, taskbar, time

A few months back, Windows 11 got an update that allowed you to show seconds in the taskbar clock like you could in Windows 10 and previous versions.

It worked fine for a while, but when the cumulative update for this month installed, my seconds were gone. I checked in the settings for the `Display seconds in system clock` setting, but it was not there. I have also tried creating the `ShowSecondsInSystemClock` `DWORD` in:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

and setting it to `1`, but this has not worked either.

Has anyone else run into this issue and found a resolution that does **not** involve using a third-party app?

Comment: In *Settings > Personalization > Taskbar > Taskbar behaviors*, do you see the option “Show seconds in system tray clock”? The strange part in your post is that KB5027231 is the update that brought seconds to the taskbar. Are you running an Insider version of Windows 11?

Comment: @harrymc I do not see that option; that was the option I was referencing above, I just got the wording confused with the registry key. I am not in the Insider program or anything similar; winver shows my build version as 22621.1848 if that helps any. All I know besides that is that I had the option in settings and it was working previously, I don't remember which exact update enabled it because it was a month or two ago.

Comment: See [this article](https://pureinfotech.com/kb5027231-windows-11-build-22621-1848-moment-3-update/). I have no explanation here, except two: (1) The update was badly installed, (2) Microsoft postponed the seconds feature to a later version. If you wish to be sure your Windows is truly up to date, do a [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Comment: I am on `22621.1778` (not Insider) and I do have the option, now downloading KB5027231. It's quite confusing the info out there, but [from here](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-enable-seconds-windows-11-clock/?newsletter_popup=1) it seems that this feature came with KB5026446 (last week) but they still write that it's the Moment 3 update...

Comment: It was added in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-24-2023-windows-configuration-update-cae8524a-4b62-4d38-bb67-f070bd282fff#:~:text=New!%20You%20can%20now%20choose%20to%20display%20seconds%20in%20the%20clock%20on%20the%20system%20tray.%20To%20turn%20this%20on%2C%20go%20to%20the%20Taskbar%20behaviors%20section%20in%20Settings%20%3E%20Personalization%20%3E%20Taskbar.%20You%20can%20also%20right%2Dclick%20the%20taskbar%20to%20quickly%20get%20to%20taskbar%20settings.

Comment: I updated (with KB5027231) to `22621.1848` and I still have this feature working. @Kurausukun what other updates do you have in the history? (see mine https://imgur.com/a/UVDadbw) Also can you put a screenshot of the Settings > Personalization > Taskbar > Taskbar behaviors page?

Comment: @YisroelTech Here is a screenshot of my most recent updates: https://imgur.com/a/1v4aHe6 and here is a screenshot of my taskbar behaviors: https://imgur.com/3XPTr9x I can try the repair install which harrymc suggested as well, provided it doesn't delete my files or settings.

Comment: Yeah, that's super odd! The repair install doesn't delete files or settings (just make sure to follow the guide, especially step 15 where you choose what to keep.)

Comment: Well if there's really nobody else having the issue then I'll probably just make a backup of my whole drive just in case and try the repair install.

Comment: The setting for seconds is there on 3 Windows 11 machines: 2 Production and 1 Insider and working fine. So perhaps a repair install will help.

Comment: Finally was able to find one of my devices that also had this issue, where it (still) didn't have the seconds option after the latest update. And I think I cracked the issue... I'll post an answer

Comment: @YisroelTech I will wait excitedly for this answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft decided that this feature isn't ready for everyone... it's only for the cool guys ...

They introduced last month a new approach to feature rollouts which they call controlled feature rollout (CFR) (see [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2222815) more about it), and now they moved this feature (*Show seconds in System Tray Clock*) under this thing, so devices that aren't yet "eligible" for this rollout lost it even if they had it before.

Thankfully they added the option to ***Get the latest updates as soon as they're available*** which basically skips the line of the devices waiting for the controlled rollout and gives you all the latest features. It can be enabled in the Windows Updates page in Settings:
[image]

Once this is turned On ***Check for updates*** again and you'll get a new type of update called *Windows configuration update* (doesn't have a KB and is in the Updated History under *Other Updates*:
[image]

Once installed and restarted the feature should be back in settings:
[image]

Comment: This comes from the fact, Microsoft A/B tests features like this, I sort of suspected I had read somewhere that this addition wasn’t a literal feature of Monument 3.

Comment: At least now they give an option to get the most recent ones if you want it

Comment: You are my savior, this worked instantly. Gotta love Microsoft, transparent as ever.

Comment: I don't even have that option, "Get the latest updates as soon as they're available." Does that require an Insider build? What update did you notice that that arrived at?

Comment: No, it doesn't need Windows insider. What version of Windows are you on, and are you fully up-to-date?